# Mvn clean install Error, Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit

Tags: java, maven, configuration

My device is windows 10 
I have Java installed and the variables configured, MVN is also configured

```
Enviornment Variables 
JAVA_HOME -> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181
M2_HOME -> C:\Program Files\Apache\Maven
MAVEN_HOME -> C:\Program Files\Apache\Maven

Path Variables are configured 
%M2_HOME%\bin
%JAVA_HOME%\bin

C:\Users>java -version
java version "1.8.0_181"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)

C:\Users>javac -version
javac 1.8.0_181

C:\Users>mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.5.4 (1edded0938998edf8bf061f1ceb3cfdeccf443fe; 2018-06-18T00:03:14+05:30)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\Apache\Maven\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_181, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Still, when I try to mvn build a client it throws the below error

```
> [INFO] --- clojure-maven-plugin:1.3.23:test (test-clojure) @
> clientname-rules --- Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
> Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit. Unrecognized
> option:
```

-

Could someone tell me what could be the problem

Comment: I had this error when doing a wsimport via the maven menu in intellij. I went to
Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven -> Importing and updated the  setting: "JDK for importer".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was because I had cloned the git folder in a folder which didn't have execute permission for me. 
Once I had cloned the folder outside that parent folder the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using windows you need to add _JAVA_OPTIONS to your environnement variable.
see here http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/faq/id-1761312/fix-create-java-virtual-machine-issue.html

Comment: I have added _JAVA_OPTIONS to your environment variable. It was failing with 512 mb hence added it as 1024mb. Each time i build a project it shows 
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx1024M
But still fails with the above error.
Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.